# Cantor set as an intersection

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I've seen that the Cantor set $C$ can be expressed as a countable intersection of $C_n$'s where $C_n=C_{n-1}-\bigcup_{k=0}^{3^{n-1}-1}(\frac{3k+1}{3^n},\frac{3k+2}{3^n})$.

Taking $C_1,C_2$ into consideration, this is clear, however, when trying to come up with this specific equation on my own, I cannot. I mean, how can we be sure that inductively, this formulation gives the correct $C_n$'s as we know.

Comment: I would draw the first few of $C_1$, $C_2$, etc., and try to describe how I got from $C_1$ to $C_2$, from $C_2$ to $C_3$, etc., mathematically, and try to find a pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure about your formula: you presumably start the recurrence at $n=1$, with $C_0=[0,1]$, and then you delete one interval. So far so good. But then you should only delete two after that (since there are two intervals left to remove middle thirds from), but in your formula you go from $0$ to $2$ which is $3$ intervals. The problem gets worse as you increase $n$. So either your formula is wrong or else you are double counting certain intervals.

Comment: yes I tried that, but I don't get why putting 3k+1, 3k+2 on the numerator kills off every open interval to be subtracted.

Comment: The formula is correct. In $n=2$, there is some open interval that doesn't intersect $C_1$ so you will only delete two intervals.

Answer (score 1):

What might help is to see that the formula in the question is a piece of the inductive proof of a closed form description of $C_n$, expressed using trinary expansions of integers.

For each $n$, each integer $k \in \{0,...,3^n-1\}$ can be written as a trinary number $a_{n-1}a_{n-2}...a_0$ with entries in the set of trigits $\{0,1,2\}$, such that 
$$k = a_{n-1}3^{n-1} + ... + a_1 3^1 + a_0 3^0
$$
Let $T_n$ be the set of such integers whose trinary expansion contains no $1$'s. For example, $T_1 = \{0,2\}$. Also, $T_2 = \{0,2,7,9\}$ which in trinary is $T_2=\{00,02,20,22\}$.

Let me sketch the proof that
$$(*) \qquad\qquad C_n = \bigcup_{k\in T_n} \biggl[ \frac{3k}{3^{n+1}}, \frac{3k+3}{3^{n+1}} \biggr]
$$
You can check easily enough that $C_0=[0,1]$, and $C_1=[0,\frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},1]$, and 
$$C_2=\biggl[0,\frac{1}{9}\biggr] \cup \biggl[\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{3}\biggr] \cup \biggl[\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{9}\biggr] \cup \biggl[\frac{8}{9},1\biggr]
$$
and that this agrees with $(*)$.

So, let's assume as an induction hypothesis that
$$C_{n-1} = \bigcup_{k=T_{n-1}} \biggl[ \frac{3k}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+3}{3^{n}} \biggr]
$$

Next, we use that $C_n$ equals what you get by removing the open middle third of each of the component intervals of $C_{n-1}$. Thus, for each $k \in T_{n-1}$, we want to remove the open middle third of the interval 
$$\biggl[ \frac{3k}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+3}{3^{n}} \biggr]
$$
which is open interval
$$\biggl( \frac{3k+1}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+2}{3^{n}} \biggr)
$$
leaving
$$\biggl[ \frac{3k}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+3}{3^{n}} \biggr] - \biggl( \frac{3k+1}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+2}{3^{n}} \biggr)
$$
and taking their union gives us $C_n$ and the formula
$$C_n = \bigcup_{k \in T_{n-1}} \biggl[ \frac{3k}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+3}{3^{n}} \biggr] - \biggl( \frac{3k+1}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+2}{3^{n}} \biggr)
$$
Collecting all the first terms of each summand we get the formula in your question:
$$C_n = C_{n-1} - \bigcup_{k=1}^{3^{n-1}-1}\biggl( \frac{3k+1}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+2}{3^{n}} \biggr)
$$
Thus, your formula is the exact expression of the statement that $C_n$ is equal to $C_{n-1}$ with the open middle thirds removed from each component interval of $C_{n-1}$.

To complete the induction, we have to do a little bit of rewriting, expressing 
$$\biggl[ \frac{3k}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+3}{3^{n}} \biggr] - \biggl( \frac{3k+1}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+2}{3^{n}} \biggr) = \biggl[ \frac{3k}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+1}{3^{n}} \biggr] \bigcup \biggl[\frac{3k+2}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+3}{3^{n}} \biggr]  
$$
and taking the union we get
$$C_n =  \bigcup_{k\in T_{n-1}} \biggl[ \frac{3k}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+1}{3^{n}} \biggr] \bigcup \biggl[\frac{3k+2}{3^{n}}, \frac{3k+3}{3^{n}} \biggr] 
$$
Now with a bit more rewriting of the union, you can finish the induction and get the formula for $C_n$ at the beginning of this answer, using the trinary arithmetic fact that 
$$T_n = \bigcup_{k \in T_{n-1}} \{3k,3k+2\}
$$

Comment: How does this answer help?

Comment: @ElChapo: I added some details.

Comment: Sorry for digging out this old answer, but I just stumbled upon it. There must be a mistake somewhere in the "proof", because $\cup_{k=0}^{3^n-1} [\frac{3k}{3^{n+1}},\frac{3k+3}{3^{n+1}}] = [0,1]$ for all $n$.

Comment: You're right, one must take the union only over those values of $k$ whose trinary expansion has no 1's. I'll make that correction.